# Rounded curve rectangle bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to add a round white curve border but unlikely it's not rendered in bitmap.

Here it is what I have done so far.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

And it's well rounded bitmap rendered with this code.

[image]

What I actually want to achieve it's should be look like this with white border bitmap images.

[image]

Any help or suggestion highly appreciate. It would be great if someone points out to me where I am going wrong.

Comment: your red frame is not round, so you want it to be round or not?

Comment: Yes it should rounded i am edited this image with tools.

Comment: ok, so did you check `Canvas` documentation on how to draw such red round rectangle?

Comment: Need to add bitamp + width(Boarder) that will create new bitmap and give a color to your paint . I tried but it's not work either .

Comment: what did you try? where is the code drawing red round frame?

Comment: Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, borderSize, borderSize, null);
    return bmpWithBorder;

It's draw border but not rounded respect with bitmap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130207/discussion-between-quokmoon-and-pskink).

Comment: read `Canvas` documentation on how to draw rounded rectangular shape,  did you do that?

Comment: I go through to documentation and added Stroke to bitmap
  // draw border
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) border);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, corner, corner, paint);

and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// draw border
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
paint.setStrokeWidth((float) border); 
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, corner, corner, paint);
```

Added stroke to bitmap images and give a some pixel of corner that fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/crediticon"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/sbi"
android:background = "@drawable/roundedcornergrey"

 />
```

roundedcornergrey

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke android:color="#e0e0e0" android:width="0.5dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

</shape>
```